# Cannot get labels to update appropriately with array data from method

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uilabel

I am trying to get pre-set mileage between two points (school1 & school2).  The method I wrote called "getMileage" works appropriately using MagicalRecord and fetches the right mileage from my CoreData (e.g. PointA to PointB is 2.6 miles)

I have a picker with 2 components on it - when the user selects a name of a location from either picker I want my miles label to update with the appropriate value (2.6, 3.1, 4.0, whatever is returned from the database).

Initially it loads fine - because the array set in the getMileage method is empty as no selections have been made on the picker.  Once the picker selects something it throws an error which states:

```
2014-02-18 10:31:41.345 54 Miles[18618:70b] Our result miles are: (
    "2.6"
)
2014-02-18 10:31:41.345 54 Miles[18618:70b] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a16690
2014-02-18 10:31:41.349 54 Miles[18618:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a16690'
*** First throw call stack:
```

As you can see - the NSLog shows the appropriate miles returned from my getMileage method.

Here is the didSelectRow method of my picker:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (_tripPicker) {
        if (component == 0){
            //Get Mileage array
            NSArray *currentMiles = [self getMileage];
            //Update Labels
            begSchoolLabel.text = [_schoolArray1 objectAtIndex:row];
            _milesLabel.text = [currentMiles valueForKey:@"miles"];
        }
        if (component == 1){
            //Get Mileage array
            NSArray *currentMiles = [self getMileage];
            //Update Labels
            endSchoolLabel.text = [_schoolArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
            _milesLabel.text = [currentMiles valueForKey:@"miles"];
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my getMileage method:

```
- (NSArray *)getMileage {
    //Update the Mileage indicator to display miles between currently selected values
    NSString *begSchool = [_schoolArray1 objectAtIndex:[_tripPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSString *endSchool = [_schoolArray1 objectAtIndex:[_tripPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    NSPredicate *milesFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"beg_school=%@ AND end_school=%@", begSchool, endSchool];
    NSArray *resultMiles = [MetaMiles MR_findAllWithPredicate:milesFilter];
    if (!resultMiles || ![resultMiles count]) {
        //The first load - this displays appropriately in log letting us know there is currently nothing there
        NSLog(@"Empty Array");
    } else {
        //This confirms our result miles come out appropriately - they look like this: ("2.1")
        NSLog(@"Our result miles are: %@", [resultMiles valueForKey:@"miles"] );
    }
    return resultMiles;
}
```

The issue lies somewhere in the didSelectRow of my picker - when trying to assign the label the resultMiles ; that's when it breaks.

I have tried this as well for my 'didSelectRow' method:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (_tripPicker) {
        if (component == 0){
            //Get Mileage array
            NSArray *currentMiles = [self getMileage];
            //Update Labels
            begSchoolLabel.text = [_schoolArray1 objectAtIndex:row];
            _milesLabel.text = [currentMiles objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if (component == 1){
            //Get Mileage array
            NSArray *currentMiles = [self getMileage];
            //Update Labels
            endSchoolLabel.text = [_schoolArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
            _milesLabel.text = [currentMiles objectAtIndex:0];
        }


    }
}
```

That kicks off this error as well:

```
2014-02-18 10:44:02.099 54 Miles[18635:70b] Our result miles are: (
    "2.6"
)
2014-02-18 10:44:02.099 54 Miles[18635:70b] -[MetaMiles length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ad3960
2014-02-18 10:44:02.103 54 Miles[18635:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MetaMiles length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ad3960'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I've bashed my head against this for a while and googled and googled trying to find answers but have come up empty handed.

It's probably something very simple I'm misunderstanding or not doing.  All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
NSArray *resultMiles = [MetaMiles MR_findAllWithPredicate:milesFilter];
if (!resultMiles || ![resultMiles count]) {
    //The first load - this displays appropriately in log letting us know there is currently nothing there
    NSLog(@"Empty Array");
} else {
    //This confirms our result miles come out appropriately - they look like this: ("2.1")
    NSLog(@"Our result miles are: %@", [resultMiles valueForKey:@"miles"] );
```

This to me looks like resultMiles is not an array (maybe a dictionary) as you are using `valueForKey` to get the result, but later on you are using `objectAtIndex` which fails

Comment: You've got me on the right track I believe.  It wasn't an array - once I looked closer, the fetchrequest was an array of MetaMiles objects!  So I had to rewrite the code a little.

Now I am doing: MetaMiles *tripMiles = [resultMiles objectAtIndex:0];

Then accessing the miles with tripMiles.miles and it is displaying the miles appropriately.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to cast that number into the label.

Comment: I just did _milesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tripMiles.miles]; and life is good!  Thanks again.